# Issue with sidebar widgets not showing when I do custom queries

Tags: query-posts, sidebar

I'm having issues with this.  I have 2 while loops, each getting different custom post types.  They both work fine, except, my sidebar content i.e. widgets, is not appearing.  I think this is because I am not running the default query.

My two queries are:

```
query_posts('post_type=offered'); 
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
....content
endwhile;
```

and

```
$wanted_query = new WP_Query('post_type=wanted');
while ($wanted_query->have_posts()) : $wanted_query->the_post();
....content
endwhile;
```

However, when I try to combine them as below, I get the sidebar content but no my posts!

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&post_type=offered' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a query, you change the environment, specifically the current post and query objects. To reset things back to how they were before the query loop you should:

```
query_posts('post_type=offered'); 
if(have_posts(){
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    ....content
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query(); // reset query!!!!
```

or

```
$wanted_query = new WP_Query('post_type=wanted');
if($wantedquery->have_posts()){
    while ($wanted_query->have_posts()) : $wanted_query->the_post();
    ....content
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

etc, also, check if you have posts before doing the loop, rather than going straight into the while loop.